# Float:right command removes footer from bottom

Tags: html, css

On this page: www.incfilms.net/services,  my goal is to make that Advertising and Consulting picture move to the right side of that paragraph.

The main page has:

```
<div class="serviceinfo">I am Not a Communist is now proud to offer a new range of digital video and media services to you and your business. We're calling it INC Pro.
<p>We are able to meet and focus with our clients on finding customizable solutions that are specific to their exact needs and objectives.
<p>We encompass the expertise and capabilities to create professional quality media; offering a number of services ranging from pre 
through post production consultation, shooting and capturing, editing, color matching, audio leveling and digital mastering. 
<p>Please contact us for a quote or more information at <?php echo $adminemail; ?>  or call at <?php echo $phonenum; ?>.
</div>


<!--ADVERTISING AND CONSULTING LOGO -->
<div class="adconsul"><img src="media/advert.png" width="350" height="120"/></div>
```

And the CSS sheet has:

```
.serviceinfo {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
}
.adconsul {
    width: 350px;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 100px;

}
```

I probably shouldnt be using the float right, but is there a way I can get that picture to the right of the paragraph and keep the footer at the bottom?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a float: right in the .serviceinfo class
you'll want to use the following after floating divs

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: I put a float:left in the serviceinfo and a float right in the .adconsul.  This worked to get them sidebyside.  What does the "clearing" do to prevent the footer from coming up? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: clear: both sort of resets the whole floating thing.  I'm not sure of the details, but when you float divs left and right, when you're done you need to do a clear.  The next divs will be in their own set.